# Connect to Lotus Domino console

Tags: console, ibm-domino

I have a Lotus Domino 8 running on a headless Linux box. domino starts on boot from startup script. Is it possible to connect to the Domino console from a shell on the server to issue commands like "show tasks", "tell", etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use [Daniel Nashed's start script](http://www.nashcom.de/nshweb/pages/startscript.htm).